# SQL Server 2008 what should i do so it will not show the data, twice?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This is my query and it showing the the data twice having the same information. What should I do so it will just show the data once?

```
    SELECT 
        STUDENT.Stud_Num, STUDENT.Last_Name, STUDENT.First_Name, 
        STUDENT.Middle_Name, STUDENT.Program, CORRELATION.Corr_Code, 
        AVERAGE.Remarks, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Year, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Qtr, 
        COURSE.Course_Name, GRADES.Grades, GRADES.[No.OfTakes] 
    FROM 
        STUDENT
inner join 
        AVERAGE on STUDENT.Stud_Num = AVERAGE.Stud_Num 
inner join 
        CORRELATION on AVERAGE.Corr_Code = CORRELATION.Corr_Code 
inner join 
        ACAD_QTR_LINK on AVERAGE.Acad_Qtr_ID = ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Qtr_ID 
inner join 
        CORR_COUR_LINK on STUDENT.Stud_Num = CORR_COUR_LINK.Stud_Num 
inner join 
        COURSE on CORR_COUR_LINK.Course_Code = COURSE.Course_Code 
inner join 
        GRADES on CORR_COUR_LINK.Corr_Cour_ID = GRADES.Corr_Cour_ID 
where 
        STUDENT.Stud_Num like '%' and STUDENT.Program like '%' 
        and STUDENT.Last_Name like '%' and STUDENT.First_Name like '%' 
        and STUDENT.Middle_Name like '%' and ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Year like '%' 
        and ACAD_QTR_LINK.Qtr like '%' 
        and COURSE.Course_Name like '%' and CORRELATION.Corr_Code like '%'
```

Resulting output:

```
|StudNum|LName|FName|MName|Prog|CorrCode|Remarks|AcadYr|Qtr|CorName|Grades|No.OfTakes
|2007131|Mendo|charisn|Chucka|ECE|ece12345|7.00000|  '11-'12 |3rd|Mathema|89.000| 1
|2007131|Mendo|charisn|Chucka|ECE|ece12345|7.00000|  '11-'12 |3rd|Mathema|89.000| 1
|2007131|Mendo|charisn|Chucka|ECE|ece12345|7.00000|  '11-'12 |3rd|Electroni|65.000| 1
|2007131|Mendo|charisn|Chucka|ECE|ece12345|7.00000|  '11-'12 |3rd|Electroni|65.000| 1
```

Comment: If you find an answer please update the question. Given what you've shown it should return the records distinctly. I think there might be something that hasn't been provided but I don't know what else to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**Response 1**
If the rows are completely identical add distinct or you could group by all columns.

```
SELECT distinct STUDENT.Stud_Num, ....
```

If you could also find out what table is making the joins return more than one row or introduce additional conditions to limit them that too might eliminate the duplicate rows.

**Response 2** after seeing your comment.

```
SELECT STUDENT.Stud_Num, STUDENT.Last_Name, STUDENT.First_Name, STUDENT.Middle_Name, STUDENT.Program, CORRELATION.Corr_Code, 
AVERAGE.Remarks, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Year, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Qtr, 
COURSE.Course_Name, GRADES.Grades, GRADES.[No.OfTakes] FROM STUDENT
inner join AVERAGE on STUDENT.Stud_Num = AVERAGE.Stud_Num 
inner join CORRELATION on AVERAGE.Corr_Code = CORRELATION.Corr_Code 
inner join ACAD_QTR_LINK on AVERAGE.Acad_Qtr_ID = ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Qtr_ID 
inner join CORR_COUR_LINK on STUDENT.Stud_Num = CORR_COUR_LINK.Stud_Num 
inner join COURSE on CORR_COUR_LINK.Course_Code = COURSE.Course_Code 
inner join GRADES on CORR_COUR_LINK.Corr_Cour_ID = GRADES.Corr_Cour_ID 
where STUDENT.Stud_Num like '%' and STUDENT.Program like '%' 
and STUDENT.Last_Name like '%' and STUDENT.First_Name like '%' 
and STUDENT.Middle_Name like '%' and ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Year like '%' 
and ACAD_QTR_LINK.Qtr like '%' 
and COURSE.Course_Name like '%' and CORRELATION.Corr_Code like '%' 
group by STUDENT.Stud_Num, STUDENT.Last_Name, STUDENT.First_Name, STUDENT.Middle_Name, STUDENT.Program, CORRELATION.Corr_Code, 
AVERAGE.Remarks, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Acad_Year, ACAD_QTR_LINK.Qtr, 
COURSE.Course_Name, GRADES.Grades, GRADES.[No.OfTakes]
```

working fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f42e/5

Comment: I don't know how will I group this. I still don't know how to use "group by" with multiple inner joins

Comment: Are your duplicate rows identical? If they aren't neither of these two will answer your question I believe.

Comment: Sir thank you for giving time to answer my question but still it's not working. It's still showing the same results.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample dataset of the duplicate rows? Are the rows entirely the same?

Comment: I would like to post the screenshot so you could see it but i am not allowed to post pictures because i got only 1 reputation.

Comment: Are the rows entirely the same for your duplicates?

Comment: the rows are entirely the same sir.